# Images.jl: How to `load` an `Image` from a URL

Tags: image, url, julia

Is it possible to `load` an `Image` from a remote URL using `Images.jl`, the same way you would load from a local file?

For reference:

```
using Images
yuss = load("mylocalimage.jpg")  # Hooray
fail = load("https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2@2x.png")  # Sad
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to use the `yuss` success in the question to fix the `fail` problem:

```
using Images
img = mktemp() do fn,f
    download("https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2@2x.png", fn)
    load(fn)
end
```

Or instead of using an external download tool, the HTTP package can be used (also this avoids the `do` syntax which might confuse):

```
using Images
using HTTP
t = tempname()
HTTP.download("https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2@2x.png", t)
img = load(t)
rm(t)
```

Admittedly, using a temporary file is not the prettiest code. Is this enough for Hooray?

ADDITION

See other answer for an even shorter version thanks to Simon Danish.

Answer (score 3):

@Simon Danisch sent me a pretty good solution offline:

```
julia> using FileIO
julia> download("https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2@2x.png") |> load
```

Apparently `download()` defaults to creating a temporary file, and returns the full-name of it as a string. Basically the same as @Dan Getz's answer, but a bit simpler.

It's too bad we have to interact with the file system at all, but I suppose this will do for now.

Answer (score 1):

Using HTTP.jl to stream the image without saving a temporary file on disk:

```
using HTTP, Images
url = "https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6933510/107239146-dcc3fd00-6a28-11eb-8c7b-41aaf6618935.png" 
philip = HTTP.get(url).body |> IOBuffer |> load
```